# Feature of importance in 1D CNN

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification

I used a simple CNN in Pytorch for classification. The input is data in csv files. The output is label 0 and 1. How do I know which variable in dataset is important? Is there a feature of importance graph for CNN? Thanks

I hope to visualize the importance of each variable for this CNN model.